# Is it possible to continue baking Rigid Body Physics

Tags: baking, rigid-body-simulation

In Blender, I already baked Rigid Body Physics for about 200 frames. Is it possible to continue baking, or do I need to *Free Bake* or *Free all Bakes* and start all over again?

[image]

Comment: Very relevant question indeed. But to state the obvious: a simulation is about capturing complex physics interactions. In principle there is no *generic* way to pick up such a process, other than running the simulation process over again from start.

Answer (score 5):

What you *should* be able to do is 'Free Bake' but leave the baked frames in the memory cache (the frames in the timeline should switch to being marked in lighter orange instead of dark orange). Then play your animation (without changing anything about the objects which were previously baked) and Blender should play the 'cached' frames and then continue the animation from the point where the baked frames stopped. Once Blender has completed the simulation up to the new end point then click Current Cache to Bake to convert the cached frames back to a baked animation - without re-simulating.

Note, however, that you have to be very careful not to change anything about the animated objects - otherwise Blender will discard the cache and start afresh when you 'play' the animation, losing your bake. You should ensure that everything about your project (including the baked cache files) is backed up before you try this so as to not risk losing your previous bake if something goes wrong.

Comment: the baked rigid data is stored in the blend-file itself, and not separately in a folder as is in the case of fluid baking right?

Comment: @FacebFaceb Yes - it is for Rigid Body - but the same principle should apply for other sim types (Cloth, Soft Body, Hair, etc.)

Comment: Of course, it would always be safer to re-bake the whole simulation if that's possible.

Comment: After moving some objects, when I am rebaking it doesn't overwrite the data, but continues, how can I start over again?

Comment: Free Bake or Free All Bakes should reset the simulation. After freeing, moving back to frame 1 should take you back to the start of the animation and playing from there should simulate afresh. Alternatively, Back following the 'Free' should re-back afresh and should not use the previous simulation at all. If it is then something unusual is happening - perhaps ask that as a separate questions (since this one was regarding specifically continuing from the existing bake).